# Does Scala have a statement equivalent to ML's "as" construct?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, sml

In ML, one can assign names for each element of a matched pattern:

```
fun findPair n nil = NONE
| findPair n (head as (n1, _))::rest =
    if n = n1 then (SOME head) else (findPair n rest)
```

In this code, I defined an alias for the first pair of the list and matched the contents of the pair. Is there an equivalent construct in Scala?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do [variable binding](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html#sec:var-binding) with the `@` symbol, e.g.:

```
scala> val wholeList @ List(x, _*) = List(1,2,3)
wholeList: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
x: Int = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you'll get a more complete answer later as I'm not sure how to write it recursively like your example, but maybe this variation would work for you:

```
scala> val pairs = List((1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c"))
pairs: List[(Int, String)] = List((1,a), (2,b), (3,c))

scala> val n = 2
n: Int = 2

scala> pairs find {e => e._1 == n}
res0: Option[(Int, String)] = Some((2,b))
```

---

OK, next attempt at direct translation. How about this?

```
scala> def findPair[A, B](n: A, p: List[Tuple2[A, B]]): Option[Tuple2[A, B]] = p match {
     | case Nil => None
     | case head::rest if head._1 == n => Some(head)
     | case _::rest => findPair(n, rest)
     | }
findPair: [A, B](n: A, p: List[(A, B)])Option[(A, B)]
```

Comment: The code I posted was just an example to demonstrate the behavior of the operator I'm looking for. I'm interested in whether the "as" operator exists in Scala in some form.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I really don't care about the little algorithm I posted. The point was to rename match variables. I edited your answer to answer my own question. I'll upvote the answer once my edit goes through.