# Scala, how to access the whole match: X match {case Y(z) as matched =>

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, case-class

Is there a syntax or way in scala to access the whole matched structure in a case statement?

To clarify, if there was an "as" keyword, one could do this:

```
x match {
  case Y(z) as matched =>
    // do stuff both with "matched" and "z" here ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Scala have a statement equivalent to ML's "as" statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205726/does-scala-have-a-statement-equivalent-to-mls-as-statement)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use the `@` syntax:

```
x match {
  case matched @ Y(z) =>
    // do stuff both with "matched" and "z" here ...
  ...
}
```

From [here](http://kerflyn.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/playing-with-scalas-pattern-matching/)

Comment: This is called [variable binding](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html#sec%3avar-binding).